# how to fetch data from database in django using phpmyadmin

Tags: python, django

model.py

```
from django.db import models
class Reg(models.Model):
   First Name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   Email ID = models.CharField(max_length=20)
   TUID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
   Password = models.CharField(max_length=8)
```

how to fetch data from database without using underscore in first name

Answer (score 0):

Models work with keywords, which means you cannot have a "First Name" without the underscore, but luckily with Django, you can work like this:

```
from django.db import models

class Reg(models.Model):
    First_Name = models.CharField('First Name', max_length=10)
    Email_ID = models.CharField('Email ID', max_length=20)
    TUID = models.CharField('TUID', max_length=10)
    Password = models.CharField('Password', max_length=8)
```

So your Model will show up on forms and admin or on your front end as First Name without the underscore. You do not need to worry much about fetching from the database, use django to do all that for you with database queries . https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Comment: Can we use raw query

Comment: Yes you may, but it might get a bit messy - Reg.objects.raw('SELECT * FROM myapp_reg'), etc.